# replace future date with past date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with the field `date_of_birth` and I have imported data from CSV file.

Somehow the CSV file has converted the date of some of the rows to a future date.

For Example: If `date_of_birth` = `1926-07-18` then the table has imported it as `2026-07-18`.

I want to update only those rows which has future dates like above to original date.

Is there any easy solution?

Comment: Are you importing dates from `yy-MM-dd` format?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
update t
     set dob = dateadd(year, -100, dob)
     where dob > getdate();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Update YourTable Set date_of_birth = DateAdd(YY,-100,date_of_birth)
  Where date_of_birth > GetDate()
```